# How to store AABB's to quickly find intersections?

Tags: javascript, svg, spatial, intersection

I am creating a web application that will display 1000's of tiny svg graphics. Each svg can be represented by an axis aligned bounding box (AABB) for easy picking. I want to allow users to drag select multiple svgs by creating a selection box (also an Aabb). How should I store all the svg AABB's so that I can quickly find which svg AABB's are intersecting with the user selection aabb?

If I store all the svg AABB's in a list, then I would have to traverse through the entire list checking if each one intersects with the selection aabb. This seems slow. There must be a better way to store the svg AABB's spatially so that I only need to test a few aabb intersections to find all the ones I need.

Comment: Maybe you'll find this useful: Quadtree: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQx_NmCIuCY&t=949s

Comment: Adding to the quadtree idea, [tag:d3.js] has an [implementation](https://github.com/d3/d3-quadtree). [This example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4343214) seems to be pretty close to what you want to achieve.

Comment: I like the idea of using quad trees, but how do I store an aabb in a quad tree? Do I store all 4 corner points in the tree with some extra info about which aabb belongs to each point stored?

Comment: Consider looking for an "AABB tree"; for example, the CGAL library, among others, has an implementation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After doing some searching based on the suggestions from others I have found what I need: https://github.com/d3/d3-quadtree and https://github.com/mikechambers/ExamplesByMesh/tree/master/JavaScript/QuadTree

Answer (score 0):

What a about if you store them as a hash table, an example would be

```
const elements = {
             ID_1: elementWithId_1,
             ID_2: elementWithId_2,
             ID_3: elementWithId_3,
             // and so on ....
           }
```

Each element into the `elements` object represents your SVG item, so when you intersect the elements, then you can pick like this,

```
if(elementA.intersects(elementB)) {
  const elementIntersected = elements[elementA.id];
   // now you Can handle your intersected element 
}
```

Hope it can help you

Comment: Storing the aabb's in a hash table does not help because I still have to iterate over all of them to find which intersect with the selection aabb's.  Quad trees seem like the better approach